# Symfony2 doctrine declaring entities to maintain inheritance with separate DB tables

Tags: inheritance, symfony, doctrine

I am writing a program to keep track of sails that can be ordered by customers.
my program has the following class structure:

```
Sail
    - mainsail
    - jib
    - spinnaker
```

I am unsure whether to use mappedsuperclass or some other doctrine inheritance type to maintain the following type of relationship within the program:

```
Mainsail extends Sail
```

I want the database itself (mySQL) to have a mainsail, jib, and spinnaker table separately.

So far, I only have a Mainsail entity/ class in my Co/QuoteBundle/Entity folder:

```
namespace Co\QuoteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Mainsail
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Co\QuoteBundle\Entity\MainsailRepository")
 */
class Mainsail
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Boat", inversedBy="mainsails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="boat_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $boatType;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="build_price", type="decimal")
     */
    private $buildPrice;

    //other variables, plus doctrine-generated getters and setters
}
```

ultimately, my goal would be to be able to not have to duplicate the same functions for all sail classes, so that I could just send a sail array into twig and where applicable treat them all as the same type, or different types.

```
{% for sail in sails %}
    <p>{{sail.name}} (${{sail.buildPrice}})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want individual tables each sharing common attributes then class-table-inheritance is your best choice: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

It really depends on how many differences there are between the different types of sails.  If it is just a couple of attributes then single table inheritance is faster and might suit your needs.  Read the chapter on inheritance carefully.

Comment: From my understanding, that adds an extra table to the database itself? What I did the other day was simply create an abstract class with the getters and setters of each inheriting class defined as abstract. Thus I have abstract class AbstractSail and classes such as Mainsail extends AbstractSail. That still requires me to essentially copy the private variables from class to class, but it guarantees that there are at least the same getters and setters in each inheriting class. Is that strategy valid?

Comment: To answer my own question, this doesn't add an extra table. That is created by many to many inheritance through a `@JoinTable` annotation. I ended up not making the class abstract since it wouldn't show up in the database that way, and I couldn't have a central DB table to store boat-sail relationships, which is what the `sail` table is mostly used for.

I marked this as the answer since it gave me a good start.  I included my full solution below. Thanks @Cerad

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Cerad's answer, I came up with the following DB schema:

```
sail {id (int), boat_id (int), discr (varchar), options (bool)}
mainsail {id (int), name (varchar), build_price (decimal), weight_lbs (decimal)}
jib {id (int), name (varchar), build_price (decimal), weight_lbs (decimal)}
spinnaker {id (int), name (varchar), build_price (decimal), weight_lbs (decimal)}
```

This was generated by running

```
$php app/console doctrine:generate:entities {packagename}
$php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

off of the following code:

(doctrine generates the discr column off of the annotations)

Sail class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Co\QuoteBundle\Entity\SailRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="sail")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"main" = "Mainsail", "jib" = "Jib", "genoa" = "Genoa", "spinnaker" = "Spinnaker"})
 */
class Sail {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;    

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Boat", inversedBy="sails")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="boat_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $boatType;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="options", type="boolean")
 */
private $hasOptions;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SailOption", mappedBy="owningSail")
*/
private $optionChoices;

//setters and getters generated by doctrine
```

mainsail class (jib and spinnaker are identical):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Mainsail
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mainsail")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Co\QuoteBundle\Entity\MainsailRepository")
 */
class Mainsail extends Sail {


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="descr", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $descr;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="build_price", type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2)
 */
private $buildPrice;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="weight_lbs", type="decimal", precision=4, scale=1)
 */
private $weightLbs;

//getters and setters generated by doctrine
```

Yes, there is redundancy in the name, build_price and weight variables. I left them in separate tables because I felt that was a better approach for future development of a simple CMS to add/remove sails individually. Since I haven't tackled that issue and I am still relatively new to this, I don't know for sure if that will be the case. Comments are appreciated :)

Thanks.